# What does the phrase social arrangement generally mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> "It may fairly be said, therefore, that any {social arrangement} that remains vitally social, or vitally shared, is educative to those who participate in it."  (Source: Democracy and Education by John Dewey)

What does the phrase social arrangement generally mean? Could you help me clarify it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, in this context, the term means "the way things are arranged socially", or possibly *societally*. It is how a social structure, or a society, is arranged - or more precisely, some part of how it is arranged, or how some part of it is arranged.

It is arguing that any such arrangement that is *vitally* social/shared, must by that nature be educative (or *educational*). I'm not 100% on the use of vitally, this all seems a little old fashioned in word choice, but I suspect it might be read as *essentially* or *at its core* in this instance.